# vlookup on csv using all 4 columns from file2 to File1 using awk

Tags: unix, awk, ksh

Trying to do a vlookup on 4 columns on a large dataset of csv file

F1 : File1

```
TSM,TYPE,NODE,SCHED
AIXTSM1,VHOST,10.199.114.72,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD
AIXTSM1,VHOST,ADMET007,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD3
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ADMET014,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD
AIXTSM1,VHOST,AGGREGATE,DAILY_2200_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD5
```

F2

```
AIXTSM1,VHOST,10.199.114.72,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD,YES
AIXTSM1,VHOST,ADMET007,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD3,NO
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ADMET014,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,YES
AIXTSM1,VHOST,AGGREGATE4,DAILY_2200_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD5,NA
```

Desired Result on 17th on F1 : Input File1

```
TSM,TYPE,NODE,SCHED,2018-11-17
AIXTSM1,VHOST,10.199.114.72,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD,YES
AIXTSM1,VHOST,ADMET007,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD3,NO
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ADMET014,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,YES
AIXTSM1,VHOST,AGGREGATE,DAILY_2200_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD5,NA
```

Desired Result after execuring code on 18th F2 : Input File1

```
TSM,TYPE,NODE,SCHED,2018-11-17,2018-11-18
AIXTSM1,VHOST,10.199.114.72,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD,YES,YES
AIXTSM1,VHOST,ADMET007,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD3,NO,NO
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ADMET014,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,YES,YES
AIXTSM1,VHOST,AGGREGATE,DAILY_2200_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD5,NA,NA
```

Code

```
awk -F, -v date=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d') ' BEGIN   { OFS = FS } FNR==NR { a[$1] = $5; next } FNR==1  { n1 = n = NF + 1; $n = date; print; next } { $n1 = ($1 in a) ? a[$1] : "NA"; print }' f2 f1 > t && mv -f t f1
```

Result is not correct with above code

Comment: Could you please confirm if your last line is NOT actual result? Since it looks like they DO NOT have 4 fields common in both the files, please confirm once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your last line shown in your expected output doesn't look to be following your rule shown, could you please try following.

```
awk -F, -v DAT=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d') '
FNR!=NR && FNR==1{
  print $0","DAT
  next
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$1,$2,$3,$4]=$0
  next
}
{
  $0=(($1,$2,$3,$4) in a)?a[$1,$2,$3,$4]:$0"," $NF ",NA"
}
1
'  Input_file2   Input_file1
```

Append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` in case you want to save output into Input_file itself.

Comment: yes , but last line is skipped using the code in results
AIXTSM1,VHOST,AGGREGATE,DAILY_2200_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD5,NA
how to use code search caseinsensitive .

Comment: @J.RAM, why you need it? I am not getting since its 4 fields are not common, please explain? Which file you want to save output too?

Comment: @J.RAM, `AGGREGATE` is there in file1 and `AGGREGATE4` is in file2 how they are common? Please explain it once.

Comment: if 4 fields are not common for any row on f1 , how to adjust code show as NA for unmatched row in results , Yes  output is redirected to Input_file1 , please help understand how its printing $5 from Inputfile2 , in code $5 is not used .

Comment: @J.RAM, try my edited code now and let me know? I will add non-one liner form of solution too now.

Comment: @J.RAM, try to print it first once it works fine for me, let me know how it goes then?

Comment: @J.RAM, it is working fine for me I double checked now.

Comment: Yes it work once , but not working on second time appending it

Comment: @J.RAM, sorry I didn't get it, second time appending it where? To save into same file or anything else?

Comment: Tried using  "> t && mv -f t f1 " along with your code , on second time matched patern are not displayed

Comment: Tried using  "> t && mv -f t f1 " along with your code , on second time matched patern is not displayed under 2018-11-17 on last column
only NA,NA is working (Unmatched pattern )


Desired Result 
TSM,TYPE,NODE,SCHED,2018-11-17,2018-11-17
AIXTSM1,VHOST,10.199.114.72,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD,YES,YES
AIXTSM1,VHOST,ADMET007,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD3,NO,NO
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ADMET014,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,YES,YES
AIXTSM1,VHOST,AGGREGATE,DAILY_2200_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD5,NA,NA

Comment: @J.RAM, not sure it is working fine for me, could you please try once `cat -v Input_file` and see if you have carriage returns in it?

Comment: No its not working , no carriage returns , every time if its executed results in a new column on File1 , similar to how we add a new column on excel and vooklup the results to that column

Comment: @J.RAM, you could paste the output which you are getting into backticks in comments and let me know then?

Comment: This is the Ouput after executing twice . Date is added twice , but results are only once , added > t && mv -f t f1 with above command .

cat f1

TSM,TYPE,NODE,SCHED,2018-11-18,2018-11-18
AIXTSM1,VHOST,10.199.114.72,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD,YES
AIXTSM1,VHOST,ADMET007,DAILY_1800_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD3,NO
AIXTSM2,VHOST,ADMET014,DAILY_1900_VM_UDC-CTL-PROD,YES
AIXTSM1,VHOST,AGGREGATE,DAILY_2200_VM_SDC-CTL-PROD5,NA

Comment: Every time when i run the code , how to append the result of matched and unmatched pattern as last column in File1 F1

Comment: @J.RAM, really not getting it, you need to show me in CODE TAGS in comments wrap them in two starting and ending backticks and let me know.

Comment: @J.RAM, you only need to print last field 2 times? Check my edit now. Please don't change requirements and once it is done we have to CLEAN all these comments to keep the post clear, let me know?

Comment: @ Ravinder Singh13 , Edited desired result in Question section